# Limiting WebDriver scope is not working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Can anyone please explain why `data.size()` is coming up as 13 and why `data1.size()` is coming up as 364?

As per my understanding, `data.size()` should be 0 because `<td>` is not a valid xpath expression and `data1.size()` should be 13 as there are 13 `<td>` tags inside/under the precipitation element. 364 is actually the total number of "td" tags in the particular webpage.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/York");
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
WebElement precipitation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Precipitation']//ancestor::tr"));
a.moveToElement(precipitation).build().perform();
List<WebElement> data = precipitation.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
List<WebElement> data1 = precipitation.findElements(By.xpath("//td"));
List<WebElement> data2 = precipitation.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
List<WebElement> data3 = precipitation.findElements(By.cssSelector("td"));
List<WebElement> data4 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td"));
List<WebElement> data5 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
List<WebElement> data6 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("abcxyz"));
System.out.println("data = " +data.size());
System.out.println("data1 = " +data1.size());
System.out.println("data2 = " +data2.size());
System.out.println("data3 = " +data3.size());
System.out.println("data4 = " +data4.size());
System.out.println("data5 = " +data5.size());
System.out.println("data6 = " +data6.size());
driver.close();
```

Comment: The output of the above code is 
data = 13
data1 = 364
data2 = 13
data3 = 13
data4 = 364
data5 = 0
data6 = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `"td"` is a valid expression, it selects the nodes with node name `td`, and since you are not using `/` or `//` the search doesn't start in a higher element in the DOM hierarchy. This means that

```
precipitation.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
```

is the equivalent of

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Precipitation']//ancestor::tr/td"));
```

`//` will locate all the matching elements in the DOM, i.e. all the `<td>` nodes. If you want to use `precipitation` as the root node and start the search from there you need to add `.` for current context

```
precipitation.findElements(By.xpath(".//td"));
```

for all `<td>`s under the `<tr>`, or

```
precipitation.findElements(By.xpath("./td"));
```

for direct children of the `<tr>`

See [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

### Selecting Nodes

XPath uses path expressions to select nodes in an XML document. The node is selected by the help of the following semantics:

[image: Selecting Nodes]

So as per the discussion above once you identify the webElement **precipitation**

```
WebElement precipitation = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Precipitation']//ancestor::tr"));
```

next to get the descendent *`<td>`* tags instead of:

```
List<WebElement> data = precipitation.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
```

As per the discussion above to identify the desired descendant *`<td>`* elements in the most effective way, you need to append the `/` character to denote from the from which node you would initiate the search.

So effectively, your line of code will be:

```
List<WebElement> data = precipitation.findElements(By.xpath(".//td"));
```

In a single line:

```
List<WebElement> data = precipitation.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@title='Precipitation']//ancestor::tr//td"));
```

which would select for you the correct **13** nos of desired `<td>` nodes.

[image: td nodes]

Comment: Okay, I understood the explanation, but then, if the nodename itself is a valid Xpath expression, then why, when I'm doing a List<WebElement> data5 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("td")) and I'm getting data5 = 0 when I am printing out the value of data5?
Why is it that "td" is now not a valid XPath expression when using driver.findElements() instead of precipitation.findElements ()?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if `data5 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("td"))` is a valid xpath. I tend to follow the best practices which I have detailed out within this answer and for a valid xpath, the referred node should be always preceeded by `.//`